# Why does break in a for loop not work when finally is involved in beanshell

Tags: beanshell

This code:

```
print(" - Start");
int[] num = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
for(int i : num)
{
    print("--> "+ i);
    try
    {
        print("    . try");
        if(i == 2)
            break;
    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception e)
    {}
    finally
    {
        print("    . finally");
    }
}
print(" - End");
```

Does not work as expected. I.e. the `break` seems not to work.
Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase to "Is beanshell dead?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna say it's a BeanShell bug. Not for the reasons outlined below (those apply only to Java on the Mac), but because if you put the same code in a main method in a "classic" Java application it does not behave in the same way. That is, the break condition works.

***The following applies only to the latest version of Java on the Mac.***

I think it's a BeanShell bug. When I try changing the if to the following BeanShell hangs up:

```
if(i == 2) {
    print("trying to break");
    break;
}
```

I forced-closed it and restarted it with the command line. I see the following errors:

```
$ java -jar bsh-2.0b4.jar 
java[1119] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
java[1119] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
java[1119] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
java[1119] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: I was going for "bug", too. But what does that mean? Don't use break in BeanShell or don't use BeanShell?

Comment: The code above runs fine in Beanshell2 (http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/) - this has left me only one conclusion: Don't use BeanShell (1)....